# How to send value instead of reference in C++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, reference

I know that we must send reference to reference and we couldn't do like [this](http://cpp.sh/8hmmq):

```cpp
void f (double& a);

f(10.1); // error
```

But we already have a project that send value instead of reference and it's compile with MSVC2017. How is this possible ?

Comment: Please show the code that is compiling with MSVC2017. Since that is the code you are asking about it makes sense to show that code.

Comment: This code is fine and it passes a value to a reference `void f (const double& a); f(10.1);`. Const makes the difference.